# clang generates call to undefined function

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, compiler-bug

The following code

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

std::size_t constexpr num = 5;

using Doubles = std::array<double, num>;

struct meow {

template<typename V>
static constexpr V value(V v, std::size_t)
{
    return v;
}

template<typename V, std::size_t... Indices>
static constexpr auto make(V v, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) -> std::array<V, sizeof...(Indices)>
{
    return {{value(v, Indices)...}};
}

Doubles doubles = make(3.1415926535897932384626433, std::make_index_sequence<num>());

};

int main()
{
    meow m;
    return m.doubles.size();
}
```

is compiled by GCC in a sensible fashion, but clang tries to call `meow::make<double,0,1,2,3,4>` without generating an implementation:

https://godbolt.org/z/9Mv67GeYW

What is going on? Did I get into [IFNDR](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/08/02/the-tough-guide-to-cpp-acronyms/#ifndr) territory?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a [bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/37522) in clang, and it seems to be [fixed](https://reviews.llvm.org/D128119) in Clang 15.

This [code](https://godbolt.org/z/z37eP5scn) seems to expose the same issue, warns in clang < 15 and not in clang >= 15.

```
class A {
  template <char N>
  struct Foo {
    static constexpr char Bar() { return 0; }
  };

  using Constants = Foo<1>;

  char var = Constants::Bar();
};
```